# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource - Only on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I am getting following error message only in chrome. Same request returns data in IE.

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://XXXXX/GetInfo. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://YYY:922' is therefore not allowed access.**

If this is a CORS issue, the request should fail in both the browsers. I am not setting any specific headers when making the request.

**Header info sent by IE**

```
Key Value
Request POST /GetInfo HTTP/1.1
Accept  */*
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer https://YYY:922/html/abc.html
Accept-Language en-US
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host    XXXXX
Content-Length  6
DNT 1
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
```

**Header info sent by Chrome**

```
POST /GetInfo HTTP/1.1
Host: XXXXX
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 7
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
Origin: https://YYY:922
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: https://YYY:922/html/abc.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: have you checked if preflight requests are being sent by chrome?

Comment: Is the origin localhost? Chrome has cors issues when the origin is localhost.

Comment: @BobbySpeirs: Origin is not localhost

Comment: @Uknown: system is directly making POST request. I do not see any `OPTIONS` type request

Comment: @Uknown: I just added a header "content-type": "application/json" and i got this error. `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` and the request type was OPTIONS. but again, the same code is working fine in IE.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think the issue is on the request. Has your server been configured to handle any preflight requests? Because if it hasn't been then it could be what's causing your issue.

Comment: another thing you could try is to set the `Content-Type` header to `text/plain` (Note: in doing this you don't send any `OPTIONS` request which might not be ideal) as I don't actually have any information apart from the headers I can only speculate on what could be wrong

Comment: @Uknown: I am making call to another server and I am not sure if CORS is enabled on the server or not. However, since IE is returning data, I assume CORS is enabled on the server.

Comment: If IE is just making a simple request then it would work. However I don't think chrome is doing that. Which is why you getting the CORS error. Chrome is sending an `OPTIONS` request and it's getting rejected by the server because the `OPTIONS` request most likely doesn't contain the data required for the server to process the request. This could result in a `500 Internal Server Error` however being an `OPTIONS` request you would probably get the CORS error you see instead. (Assuming the server wasn't configured for `OPTIONS` requests)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152092/discussion-between-uknown-and-sharpcoder).

Comment: @Uknown: mu corporate proxy does not allow me to chat